# os.PathError does not implement error

Tags: go, error-handling, interface

The [`PathError`](https://golang.org/src/os/error.go?s=750:813#L17) type found in Golang's `os` library:

```
type PathError struct {
    Op   string
    Path string
    Err  error
}

func (e *PathError) Error() string { return e.Op + " " + e.Path + ": " + e.Err.Error() }
```

*nearly* fulfills Go's [`error` interface](https://golang.org/src/builtin/builtin.go?s=10990:11030#L245):

```
type error interface {
    Error() string
}
```

However, when trying to pass it as an error, you get the following compile time error:

```
cannot use (type os.PathError) as type error in argument... 
os.PathError does not implement error (Error method has pointer receiver)
```

Why would `os.PathError` use a pointer receiver for the Error method, and just avoid meeting the requirements of the error interface?

Full example:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    e := os.PathError{Path: "/"}
    printError(e)
}

func printError(e error) {
    fmt.Println(e)
}
```

Comment: The compile error says: "Error method has pointer receiver". You need to use a pointer.

Comment: You will have better luck with [`printError(&e)`](https://play.golang.org/p/S9ynJV9a2ma).

Comment: (When you jump back into Go and seriously need to review.) On a side note, I fortuitously found Dave Cheney's excellent [article on errors](https://dave.cheney.net/2016/04/27/dont-just-check-errors-handle-them-gracefully) when searching for `os.PathError`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read about method sets here: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets

> The method set of any other type T consists of all methods declared with receiver type T. The method set of the corresponding pointer type *T is the set of all methods declared with receiver *T or T (that is, it also contains the method set of T)

You are trying to call a function taking the `error` interface using type `os.PathError`. According to the above, it does not implement `Error() string`, because that method is defined on type `*os.PathError`.

Having `os.PathError` you can get `*os.PathError` using the `&` operator:

`printError(&os.PathError{...})`